# Blur background based on page length

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make so that if you scroll down, a blurred picture appears (with opacity) and if you're at the bottom of the page, the blurred picture is fully visible and the old one disappeared. I'm using the same pagecontainer for every page and I want to make this script do this on every page, with different page lengths.

I have this so far:

CSS:

```
.img-src {
    position: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.blurred-img {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
var divs = $('.social, .title'),
limit = 0;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st <= limit) {
       $('.blurred-img').css({ 'opacity' : (1 - st/limit) });
   }
});
```

Comment: So what is it doing/not doing vs what is expected?

Comment: Why don't you just use `filter: blur()`?

Comment: @takendarkk It's blurring but at long pages, it's full-blurred in the middle of the page, and at small pages, it's only half-blurred (or less) at the end of the page.

Comment: @gcampbell It's not actually blurring, it's fluently going into a dark version of the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter: blur` usually works fine and looks better. How about something like this?

```js
var img = document.getElementById("background-img");
var container = document.body;
var maxBlur = 20;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  var position = container.scrollTop / (container.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight);
  // Adjust the position for safari that may scroll higher or lower than the 
  // actual size during their "bounce effect".
  position = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, position));
  var blurAmount = position * maxBlur;
  img.style["filter"] = "blur(" + blurAmount + "px)";
});
```

```css
#background-img {
  position: fixed;
}
#spacer {
  width: 50px;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<img id="background-img"  src="http://placehold.it/400x200?text=Background" />
<div id="spacer"></div>
```

If you really want to do your two images strategy, here is how I would do it.

```js
var img = document.getElementById("blured-background-img");
var container = document.body;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  var opacity = container.scrollTop / (container.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight);
  // Adjust the opacity for safari that may scroll higher or lower than the 
  // actual size during their "bounce effect".
  opacity = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, opacity));
  img.style["opacity"] = opacity;
});
```

```css
#background-img {
  position: fixed;
}
#blured-background-img {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
}
#spacer {
  width: 50px;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<img id="background-img"  src="http://placehold.it/400x200/7A6DFF/D3CFFF?text=Bottom" />
<img id="blured-background-img"  src="http://placehold.it/400x200?text=Top" />
<div id="spacer"></div>
```